# Google Purchase API REST call possible errors

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I am using the Purchase REST API call to check if the user has purchased an item. I noticed that sometimes the call is not successful. It returns the error message "Serving Limit Exceeded". But if I make the call again, it returns a successful result. Are there any more errors like this that I would need to handle? I did not find this documented anywhere.

`"https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/" . $packageName . "/subscriptions/" . $prodID . "/purchases/" . $token . "?access_token=" . $r ['access_token'];`